# Why does my function fail intermittently?

Tags: javascript

I need some help with this script. Can't find out why it fails sometimes.
It is working most of the time, but sometimes it's just showing blank page.

This is the script (in the folders I have 3 image files named 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg.:

```
function chgbg() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var totalCount = 3;
    var num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);

    /* Monday - Friday */
    if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 23 && h < 6) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(gfx/weekdays/00-06/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }
    if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 6 && h < 11) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(gfx/weekdays/06-11/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }
    if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 11 && h < 14) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(gfx/weekdays/11-14/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }
    if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 14 && h < 18) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(gfx/weekdays/14-18/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }
    if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 18 && h < 23) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(gfx/weekdays/18-00/' + num + '.jpg)';
    }

    /* Monday - Friday */
```

Comment: One quick thing you could do to try and find the issue is remove unneeded code. Since you are setting the background color to white in every case, there is no need to have it in any of the `if` branches.

Comment: if `n<1`.. nothing would happen i guess.. that's y a blank page would show up.. other than that your code seems solid

Comment: also @ScottMarcus he's *literally* showing the background image function which SHOULD be responsible for the background image

Comment: I'd encourage you to be less stingy with your function and variable names. Readability is important. One-letter variables and cryptic function names are a turn-off for your team members.

Comment: Your first if statement is expecting the hour to be BOTH greater than and equal to 23 AND less than 6. Which is impossible so that would never be triggered. Also, I would recommend turning every if after the first one into an `else if`.

Comment: @TheBombSquad Background colors should always be set, even when a background image is going to be used. This is a safeguard for people who may have images turned off, or in the case that the image is no longer available on the server. So, setting the color is good, but setting it over and over to the same color is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is impossible

`if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 23 && h < 6)`

`h` can't be both >=23 and <6 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it will fail on the first condition (when your hour is between 23 and 6), because you are telling javascript "if hour is equal to or greater than 23 and less than 6", and this isn't possible.

> if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && h >= 23 && h < 6)

A solution could be

> if (n >= 1 && n < 5 && (h >= 23 || (h >= 0 && h < 6)))

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in cases like this one I really like to use *loops,* which iterate over arrays of structures.  In this example, each of the cases appear to differ only by:  the boundary values for `n` and `h`, and a substring that will be inserted into the `backgroundImage` URL.  So, your code loops through this structure and, as soon as it finds a matching case, it uses `break` to get out.  Much more maintainable.